# How to get coordinates of the current visible area of a map

Tags: d3.js, svg

I wonder how to get the coordinates (longitude, latitude) of the current visible area of a map created with d3. I'm looking a solution that works for both orthographic and mercator projection.

The aim is to filter the data / shapes to apply on the map.

Here is the way I created the SVG root element to put map elements in:

```
var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append('svg')
      .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid')
      .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + width + ' ' + height)
      .attr('width', mWidth)
      .attr('height', mWidth * height / width);

svg.append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'background')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);
```

Here are the ways I create my projections:

```
var projection1 = d3.geo.orthographic()
      .scale(248)
      .clipAngle(90);

var projection2 = d3.geo.mercator()
      .translate([configuration.width / 2, configuration.height / 1.5]);
```

**Edit**

Following the Lars' answer, I tried to use the project#inverse method with orthographic projection, as described below:

```
var bbox = svg.node().getBBox();
var x1 = bbox.x;
var y1 = bbox.y;
var x2 = bbox.x+bbox.width;
var y2 = bbox.y+bbox.height;

var lonLat1 = projection.invert([x1, y1]);
var lonLat2 = projection.invert([x2, y2]);
```

Both variables `lonLat1` and `lonLat2` are `[NaN,NaN]` whatever the zoom level.

Thanks very much for your help!
Thierry

Comment: Use the projection's `.invert()` method to get the coordinates for the corners of the container.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, Lars! Could you give a link to the documentation of this function or to a sample of use?

Comment: It's just `projection1.invert([x,y])` or `projection2.invert([x,y])`.

Comment: Thanks! What remains not so obvious for me is: how to get the coordinates for the displayed area? i.e. how to get the x and y parameters to pass to the invert method?

Comment: I updated my question with my latest tests.

Comment: The coordinates would be relative to the container, i.e. `[0,0]` and `[width,height]`.

Comment: Working on this for my own project. It occurs to me that it won't be a square.